# Broadcast command in discord.py

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I am wanting to implement a cool broadcast command. The command will be like this. If an admin DMs the bot with `$bc <whatever they want to type here>` then the bot will then send that message to `#broadcast`. It can read from DMs and the server. I tried this command but it didn't work as I would have thought.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def bc(args, message):
    channel = server.get_channel("474316889435275264")
    await bot.send_message(channel, args)
```

It can't read any of the  `channel = server.get_channel("474316889435275264")`
so I know that the code is wrong.

PS: it would be like the "say" command but it would send it to a specified channel.

Comment: What if your bot is a member of more than one server?  Should it always send it to the same channel, send it to the `#broadcast` channel of that server, accept a server as an argument?

Comment: How did you get on with Patrick's reply below, Zemo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) to resolve the channel even if you don't have a reference to the server.  I assume below that you always want to send the message to a specific channel no matter where it comes from.

[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) also has special handling of [keyword only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) that allows them to capture the remaining unprocessed text of a message, instead of being split into arguments.  In your example, `bc(args, message)`, `message` would only capture a single word or force you to wrap the message in quotes.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def bc(ctx, *, message):
    channel = bot.get_channel("474316889435275264")
    await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```